# Full screen games either crash or auto minimize while in play

Tags: windows-7, gaming

Whether I'm running Dota 2 or Skyrim I'll be playing fine then BAM it will freeze up. In the case of Skyrim it will freeze for a few seconds then usually allow me to continue playing, but in the case of Dota 2 it will completely crash. I don't know why and it's really annoying because it was not doing this 3 days ago.

Specs:

- Core i7 2600 - 3.4GHz
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- GTX 590 graphics
- Windows 7 Home Premium

Would it help if I upgraded to 7 Ultimate? I have already tried completely restoring the system back to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

I would check first the `Event Viewer` (go to `Start menu` and type its name), then have a look in the `Windows Logs` -> `Application` and `System`, there could be a conflict or a failure, either a driver (audio/video), maybe a hardware failure, there is a problem related with your Operating System, or the games have some issues. The details from the log should give further hints about the issue, you could post in the question the results you found there, if other people had similar issues I'm sure this can be searched on the web (based o the hints from there).

Comment: Related to this, check what's running before you start (like the notifications area).  Try closing everything you can before you start the game and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem may be with the windows,you can repair or re installing it,or installing another copy of windows,or you could find a solution for Dota 2 crash from [here](https://www.google.com.eg/#q=dota+2+crash+to+desktop).

Comment: That's an overkill/last resort type of solution. You should be able to work out what app is misbehaving, otherwise you'll just install it again after you've reinstalled.